# root of java installation

Tags: java, hadoop

am trying to set up apache hadoop in my system. In the procedure page it says "edit the file conf/hadoop-env.sh to define at least JAVA_HOME to be the root of your Java installation. "

What does setting "JAVA_HOME" and "root of java partition" actually mean. Does the root mean the place from where java gets loaded(ie, output of "which java" command)??

Am using Fedora 12

Answer (score 6):

`JAVA_HOME` denotes the installation folder of a JRE or SDK. It contains binaries, libraries and documentation. You can find out the root installation directory by typing

```
$ which java
```

The part before the `bin/java` will typically be your `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but when i run `pig -x local` it always outputs: Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java... Is there another version of java I should use to prevent this from showing up?

Comment: figured it out. i have a mac. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372166/making-sure-java-home-is-correctly-set

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Debian) it is: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun`, file `/usr/bin/java` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/java` which is a symlink to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java`

Answer (score 1):

The path /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Some_version_number/Home/ is where mine is on Macbook pro (Lion).

Here is mine: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/

When you type 'which java' a symlink is what is returned, not the actual Java home path that you need. This path should be defined in the file conf/hadoop-env.sh which is in the root of the Hadoop package.

I'm using Hadoop and I ran into this problem. The path that I posted fixed my problem.