# Making sure JAVA_HOME is correctly set

Tags: java, macos

Pretty new to Java and also to Mac ... I want to make sure JAVA_HOME is set so in other programs I can use its path.
So I did some Googling and here is what I got:

If I enter **/usr/libexec/java_home** in terminal I get this: 
**/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home**
but if I enter **echo $JAVA_HOME** in terminal, I don't get anything back.

Can you please tell me what is going on in here?

Thanks.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=$PATH:/usr/libexec/java_home
worked for me

Answer (score 77, accepted):

JAVA_HOME isn't set by default on OSX. You can resolve this by opening terminal and executing the following:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`" >> ~/.profile    
. ~/.profile
```

This will cause JAVA_HOME to be set on startup (rather than just the current session), and immediately add it.

Comment: thanks, didn't know these. Ok how can I navigate to this place that you mentioned? "~/.profile"

Comment: I edited the answer so you can just execute those two commands and be done. For future reference, you could have done: vim ~/.profile, then press i to go into edit mode, paste in the code, then escape, press :wq, done. Vim is a good tool to learn as well :)

Comment: umm, you probably want >> instead of > in case ~/.profile already exists.

Comment: Years pass. Question: do you want " (double) quotes or ' (single) quotes around the export command? Using " quotes means we execute the _java_home_ command as part of the echo, hard-coding the resulting path. Using ' (single) quotes would execute _java_home_ every time you log in, which might be what you really want. Up to you, but I'd go for single quotes: if the path was that well defined, they wouldn't need a command to generate it! OTOH, maybe you don't want  JAVA_HOME swinging around wildly whenever you log in.

Comment: @shovavnik also running a hot reload of `~/.bash_profile` helped me further along by doing - `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 15):

## Checking JAVA_HOME path

Try running `source .bash_profile` prior to `echo $JAVA_HOME` in your root directory. This should correct the problem if you've set `JAVA_HOME` correctly. If you're not sure you're in your root directory, simply type `cd ~`, press enter and you're there.

[image: Root Directory]

- **Explanation**: `source` loads and runs your bash_profile.

If you haven't set `JAVA_HOME` correctly, following the instructions below should clear things up.

- `vim .bash_profile` — *opens your bash_profile in Vim.*

  - > *I've included a list of VIM commands you'll likely need to edit your .bash_profile below.*
- `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` — *creates an ENV_VAR (Environment Variable) and sets/stores the home path of the JDK to `(/usr/libexec/java_home)`*.
- Exit vim and type the following at the terminal*
- `source .bash_profile` — *loads and runs your updated bash_profile*
- `echo $JAVA_HOME` — *returns the value stored in the `ENV_VAR JAVA_HOME`, which is the home path of your JDK installation.*

---

> ## VIM Commands:
>
> Vim is an editor to create or edit a text file. There are two modes in vim.
>
> - **Command Mode:** user can move around the file, delete text, etc.
> - **Insert Mode:** user can insert text.
>
> ### Changing between modes:
>
> **Command mode to Insert mode**
>
> - type the appropriate letter for the action you want (a, A, i, I, o, O) -- details for letters below.
>
> **Insert mode to Command mode**
>
> - press Esc (escape key)
>
> #### Text Entry Commands *(Used to start text entry)*
>
> - **a** -- Append text following current cursor position
> - **A** -- Append text to the end of current line
> - **i** -- Insert text before the current cursor position
> - **I** -- Insert text at the beginning of the cursor line
> - **o** -- Open up a new line following the current line and add text there
> - **O** -- Open up a new line in front of the current line and add text there
>
> #### Cursor Movement Commands *(only used in the commands mode.)*
>
> - **h** -- Moves the cursor one character to the left
> - **l** -- Moves the cursor one character to the right
> - **k** -- Moves the cursor up one line
> - **j** -- Moves the cursor down one line
> - **nG or :n** -- Cursor goes to the specified (n) line
> - (ex. 10G goes to line 10)
> - **$** -- Move cursor to the end of current line
> - **0** -- (zero) Move cursor to the beginning of current line
> - **w** -- Forward one word
> - **b** -- Backward one word
>
> #### Exit Commands
>
> - **:wq** -- Write file to disk and quit the editor
> - **:q!** -- Quit (no warning)
> - **:q** -- Quit (a warning is printed if a modified file has not been saved)
> - **ZZ** -- Save workspace and quit the editor (same as :wq)

[VIM Editor Commands -- full list](http://www.radford.edu/~mhtay/CPSC120/VIM_Editor_Commands.htm)

[osx](/questions/tagged/osx)[terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal)[java](/questions/tagged/java)

Comment: Good explanation

Answer (score 6):

The empty value of the echo command would mean that the value has not been set correctly as you are expecting. You can try creating/editing ~/.profile by adding the lines something like:

```
vi ~/.profile
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

if you are not yet comfortable with **vi editor**, you may also create that file in your home directory using **TextEdit** program in Mac.
 and execute

```
source ~/.profile
```

That will load set the JAVA_HOME property. Next you can try out executing
echo $JAVA_HOME
to check whether it has been set correctly as you expect.

You may also need to set PATH environment variable as something like:

```
export PATH=PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: ok thanks, one stupid question: what is this "~" I see in so many places?

Comment: It's just an alias for the home folder of the current user. That home folder on osx would be located under /Users

Comment: oh ok ok, Then how can I find out what is the full path to my home folder?

Comment: You can just do: echo $(dirname ~/)/$(basename ~/)

Comment: Please update this to read `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` instead of `export PATH=PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` because without the "$" it wipes out the user's path so that commands like `ls` and `nano` don't work.  Many users won't understand to use `/usr/bin/nano` so they will be stuck without a working shell.  And worse, it even affects newly opened shell windows in Terminal.app, as well as `sudo`, and can be hard to recover from.  But your answer was helpful for `appium-doctor`, because Appium didn't mention how to fix "WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ Bin directory for $JAVA_HOME is not set" in their docs

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/launchd.conf` in your text editor. If it does not exist create it.

Then append the following line to the file:
`setenv JAVA_HOME /path/to/java/installation`

### OR

just type the following command in terminal
`sudo echo setenv JAVA_HOME /path/to/java/installation >> /etc/launchd.conf`
Then just enter your password when it prompts.

Now reboot your computer and the changes should have taken place.

**Note :**
 I am giving you advice based on my experience in Linux. But, these should work on 
MAC also.

[Source](http://www.digitaledgesw.com/node/31)

Comment: well I copy-pasted /etc/launchd.conf in terminal, but it says no such file or directory exists

Comment: From what I understood, after a bit of googling, /etc/launched.conf does not exist by default, so just create it.

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer. The given command should be able to create the file. Note that, making changes in /etc/launchd.conf sets JAVA_HOME for all users.

Answer (score 1):

This is not resilient to new installs of the JDK. According to Apple:
- you should not set it globally
- you should use libexec

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2011/May/msg00040.html

You might think that:

$ cat /etc/launchd.conf
setenv JAVA_HOME `/usr/libexec/java_home`

would work - but no, it sets it literally.

But, as I say, according to that Apple Engineer, you are not supposed to set it globally anyway. :(

Comment: Just in case anyone else finds this. It does work, but the grave characters are important. \`/usr/libexec/java_home\` They are eaten by the formatting here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after setting JAVA_HOME with jenv. You can solve the problem by editing file

```
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Just set path to your version of java by uncommenting / editing appropriate part of file. For AdoptOpenJDK installed with homebrew it looks like this:

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
<array>
    <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
    <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options,
                   or add a VM found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V
        <string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Commands/java</string>
        <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
    -->
        <string>-keyring</string>
    <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
</array>
```