# Cygwin failing to find Java

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I'm currently trying to configure a standalone Hadoop node on a new computer (for my own learning purposes) but when I try to find the root of my java installation using `$which java`
as per this question

[root of java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709146/root-of-java-installation)

I get the following error

```
Me@myhouse /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)
$ which java
which: no java in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive
/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32
/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static)
```

I get the exact same error message at the top level of my C: drive.

I know that Java is there - I just installed it! Can anyone explain what I have done wrong?

Comment: It seems from the Getting started with Hadoop help page that maybe I need to be using an older version of Java (1.5.x) Could this be the reason that cygwin is failing to find? Horribly confused now...

Comment: You can save yourself loads of trouble by just running linux in VirtualBox.  Windows + Cygwin rarely gets Hadoop running smoothly (although it's theoretically possible).

Comment: What dir is java installed in on your Windows C:\ drive?  That directory needs to be included in the $PATH variable in the shell.

Comment: @tommy_o It is in the Program Files (x86) drive, which I have tried to include. Cygwin hates all the special characters, but it's doable. Still doesn't find it. I'll try to post the error message when I'm back on my home machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your command just checks if java is found in the common paths from cygwin
So in cygwin you need to add the java path to the paths:
 `export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102"` 
`export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"`